# How do I prevent forced capitalization after a period in Scrivener?

Tags: scrivener, capitalization

Scrivener forces a capitalization after a period when used in initials when possessive such as J.D.’S coat. It should be J.D.’s coat. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

On my desktop (Mac) version of Scrivener:

Under PREFERENCES ––> CORRECTIONS

the 2nd toggle down is called "Fix capitalization of sentences". Switch this toggle off.

Comment: Or don't use periods in initials. Many people omit them these days, especially outside the US.